# How to subtract 08/22/2013 18:38:42 - 07/26/2013 14:56:39 with output format 2.4 days

Tags: excel, date, subtraction

How to subtract 08/22/2013 18:38:42 - 07/26/2013 14:56:39  in Excel to return in the format 2.4 days?

Comment: = DATEDIF ( start_date , end_date , unit )

Comment: How is the difference between the two dates equal 2.4 ?!?! It's more like 27+ days!

Answer (score 3):

Just subtract - so if you have start date/time in A2 and end date time in B2 you can use this formula in C2

`=B2-A2`

format C2 as number - you won't get 2.4 from your example, though. It looks more like **27.2**

Answer (score 0):

if you had selected cell format as date type, you can subtract dates like this

```
 =DATE(2013,1,2)-DATE(2012,2,1)
```

**EDIT:**

[this](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datedif.aspx) site tells you can use =DATEDIF. but it is not working in excel 2010

Comment: I don't know of any function called `DATEIF`...

Comment: oh my bad it should bi DATEDIF. now I have edited

Comment: DATEDIF works OK in Excel 2010 (although it doesn't appear in the function list) ......but it will ignore the times unlike a simple subtraction